# Get List of all elements of a particular type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How can I get the list of all elements in the project that matches the type given in the query? For example, If I specify the type as `enum`, I should get the list of all enums in the project. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: I don't have any code as of now. All I need is this. @MilindAnantwar

Comment: You need to start reading about reflection.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, will check it, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to get all accessible enums among all accessible assemblies.

With C# reflection, you can easily get all referenced assemblies with current entry. From them you can get all enums with some filters like `Where(t => t.IsEnum)`.

Example code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public static List<Type> AllAccessiableEnums()
{
    var entry = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    var referenced = entry
        .GetReferencedAssemblies()
        .Select(t => Assembly.Load(t))
        .ToList();

    referenced.Add(entry);

    return referenced
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
        .Where(t => t.IsEnum) // Use your own filter here.
        .ToList();
}
```

**Caution:** Calling this may get lots of enums from Microsoft.

[image]

Comment: I guess we can specify the areas where we need to search for enums.

Comment: @ArjunDNair Yep. Just add a filter to the `referenced` assemblies.